# How to refresh data in view model in MAUI app

Tags: maui

I have a carousel view in a XAML file:

```
     <CarouselView x:Name="AttView" ItemsSource="{Binding Attendances}" IndicatorView="indicatorView">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:AttendanceItem">
                <Grid Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" 
                          ColumnDefinitions="*, *" 
                          RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto, Auto, Auto">
                    <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Turno actual" />
                    <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TurnoActual}" />
                    <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Hora de llegada" />
                    <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding HoraLlegada, StringFormat='{0:HH:mm}'}" />
                    <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Hora de salida" />
                    <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding HoraSalida, StringFormat='{0:HH:mm}'}" />
                    <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Horas trabajadas" />
                    <Label Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding HorasTrabajadas, StringFormat='{0:hh} h {0:mm} m'}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
    <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"
               IndicatorColor="Gray"
               SelectedIndicatorColor="Black"
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

On the other hand, the viewmodel is defined this way:

```
public ObservableCollection<AttendanceItem> Attendances { get; set; }

public MainViewModel()
{
    Attendances = new ObservableCollection<AttendanceItem>
    {
        new AttendanceItem
        {
            TurnoActual = new TurnoItem
            {
                Inicio = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8),
                Fin = DateTime.Today.AddHours(18),
                Tipo = Enums.TipoTurnoEnum.Fijo
            },
            HoraLlegada = DateTime.Today.AddHours(7).AddMinutes(50)
        }
    };
}
```

And finally, this is the item of the collection:

```
public class AttendanceItem
{
    public TurnoItem TurnoActual { get; set; }
    public DateTime? HoraLlegada { get; set; }
    public DateTime? HoraSalida { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan HorasTrabajadas { 
        get { 
            if (HoraLlegada is null && HoraSalida is null)
                return TimeSpan.Zero;

            DateTime llegada = HoraLlegada ?? DateTime.Today.Add(TurnoActual.Inicio.TimeOfDay);
            DateTime salida = HoraSalida ?? DateTime.Now;

            return salida - llegada;
        } 
    }
}
```

Notice `HorasTrabajadas` property. If `HoraSalida` is null, current time should be displayed.

So the question is, how can I refresh the view so that I can see how the `HorasTrabajadas` property increments its value every 1 minute?

I tried with a timer in the view code behind, with this code:

```
    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MainViewModel.Attendances));
    }
```

But it did not work.

Comment: you can't call `PropertyChanged` on a property in a different class.  You need to expose a public method on `AttendanceItem` and then call that when the timer elapses

Comment: @Jason AttendanceItem is an item of the collection. It does not have OnPropertyChanged, however, the main view model does, so I created a public method called `RefreshAttendances` in the view model class with only this instruction `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Attendances));` , and I called `RefreshAttendances` in the timer elapsed event of the XAML code behind, but it did not update the view. Maybe something is missing.

Comment: if you expect to refresh the view based on a property of `AttendanceItem` then it **must** implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason has pointed it out that the Mode AttendanceItem must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and the data binding mechanism in .NET MAUI attaches a handler to this `PropertyChanged` event so it can be notified when a property changes and keep the target updated with the new value.

You can refer to the sample code below:

```
public class AttendanceItem: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private DateTime horaLlegada;
    public DateTime HoraLlegada
    {
         get => horaLlegada;
         set
         {
             if (horaLlegada != value)
             {
                    horaLlegada = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("HoraLlegada");
              }
         }

    }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                 new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
}
```

For more information, you can refer to [Data binding and MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm).